# path_provider_ios give an error when build iOS in Flutter 2.10.5

Tags: ios, flutter

Good Afternoon, everyone. i have to ask something about any dependency (for example i used cache_network_image dependency). When i built in iOS by 'Pod Install'. It's automatically downloaded path_provider_ios. And then when i used flutter run, i got an error message such like :

```
/Users/koffiemac/Documents/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_ios-2.0.11/ios/Classes/FLTPathProviderPlugin.m:17:40
```

Any issue between Generic Issue or Lexical issue. I don't know why it always happen in flutter dependency. did you know it ?

ps:

- I have do many solution such delete Podfile.lock or delete Runner / Flutter repository inside iOS repo. and then, flutter clean and pod install / update. but, it can't resolved.
- My XCode version is 12.4. is it a problem with Flutter 2.10.5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway, i found what's my trouble? because flutter 2.10.5 doesn't support on XCode 12.4 (i have try used cache_network_image at flutter 3.0.5 with XCode 13.4.1 and it works well). i hope flutter team get fixed it.